# MSVC evaluating context (and erroring) without knowing types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, static-assert

This code fails compilation on MSVC because the `static_assert` fails:

```
template<class MyType>
struct Test {
    static_assert(MyType(5) != MyType(6), "fails");
};
```

See: https://godbolt.org/z/vUSMHu

Any ideas how MSVC can evaluate this without even knowing what MyType is?

Even more obscure:

```
template<class MyType>
struct Test {
    static_assert(MyType(5) == MyType(6), "succeeds");
    static_assert(!(MyType(5) == MyType(6)), "fails");
};
```

See: https://godbolt.org/z/3631tu

And instantiating it (i.e. giving MyType a type) also doesn't help:

```
template<class MyType>
struct Test {
    static_assert(MyType(5) != MyType(6), "still fails");
};
Test<int> variable;
```

See: https://godbolt.org/z/yxF4h0

Or a bit more complex: https://godbolt.org/z/68g6yO

Comment: As it works both with clang and gcc and it is not a hack it is safe to assume it is compiler bug

Comment: No repro on VS2017 15.8.4. Note that godbolt VS compilers are fairly outdated. @Evg there is no MSVS 2018, it is either VS 2017 or VS 2019 (to be released)

Comment: @VTT, sorry, latest MSVS 2017 Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this strange error happens in MSVC 19.10, but it is already not reproducible in MSVC 19.14 and upward. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/635Mxdazd

So it is reasonable to assume that it was just a compiler bug.